# Issue with installing phonegap 3.3.0?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to install the phonegap version 3.3.0, So I have installed nodejs and I run the following command,

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

By running the above command I am getting the following error.[image]

Can any one suggest me the solution for the above issue?

My Project creation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install git and make sure that git paths are available on system variable path. Most likely path will be set all by itself with install.

[Git Link](http://git-scm.com/downloads)

Comment: Thank you. Where should I need to give the path

Comment: Install git first,then try to install phonegap. path should be set automatically. If not then I'll tell you how to check if path is set or not.

Comment: Everything is gets installed. Now How can I create my project?

Comment: I have installed phonegap 3.5

Comment: go to your desired directory, and run the command `phonegap create firstapp com.myapp.firstapp firstapp` This will create your project.

Comment: phonegap is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: restart your terminal/command prompt. If everything is installed perfectly then it should work.

Comment: desired location means where the phonegap.cmd located or phonegap.js file location?

Comment: No no. desired directory means where you want to create the project. Suppose you want create the project in D drive. then first use `d:` command, then this command `phonegap create firstapp com.myapp.firstapp firstapp`

Comment: Yes, have created my project, I will attached the screen shot on my question. Please check Is my project is created successfully or I need to change any thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56173/discussion-between-precious-and-atanucse).